# Websphere Application Server v9 in Eclipse Neon

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-9

We are in the process of migrating applications from WAS 7  to WAS 9.

Can you please let me know how to install WAS 9 traditional server (without the liberty profile) in eclipse neon.

I have followed the steps from the below link and I see only **Liberty** server in my run times.

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Application_Server_Migration_Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of IBM Installation Manager:

[http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27025142](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27025142)

Add the following repository to Installation Manager for Version 9.0:

https://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V9WASILAN

Select IBM WebSphere Application Server (ILAN) and install.

The detailed steps can be found here:
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/WAS_traditional_for_Developers